# How to access the array position using SwiftUI's onDelete() function

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsindexset

I am attempting to sync the UI delete with deleting a record from CloudKit. SwiftUI has the `onDelete()` function that you can add to a List view which gives you the swipe to delete gesture. I am trying to use this to access the position in the array of the deleted item so I can refer to it in another function to handle the deletion from Cloud Kit. Here is how SwiftUI sets up `onDelete()`.

```
List {
    ForEach(recordsHandler.audioRecords) { record in
        Button(action: {
            //set the showModal variable to true to show DetailModalView
            self.showModal = true
            self.recordToPass = record
        }) {
            AudioRowView(audio: record)
     }
     .sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
         PlaybackModalView(selectedRecord: self.recordToPass).environmentObject(self.recordsHandler)
     }
}
.onDelete(perform: delete)
```

Below is my custom row view. Doesn't really add much to the problem but in case it does.

```
struct AudioRowView: View {

    var audio: Audio

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(audio.title)
                .padding(5)
            Spacer()
            Text(audio.type)
                .padding(10)
                .background(Color.black)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(20)
        }
        .frame(height: 50)
    }
}
```

And below is the delete function at present which as is, provides the swipe gesture and deletes the entry from the list view. As stated I am now trying to decipher what position in the array the row was and so I can call it in another function and proceed with deleting the entry from CloudKit.

```
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    recordsHandler.audioRecords.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are given the offsets, so you can tell one by one:

```
 func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
recordsHandler.audioRecords.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    for row in offsets{
        print(row)}
}
```

Comment: So when this is implemented you get an **index out of range** error when i try to access the last row and if I add - 1 i will get the same error.

Also it seems that the offset isn't 1 to 1 with the array in regards to the items and their position. I am sure the answer is pretty simple but I've been reading through the documentation and it hasn't clicked yet

Comment: show your code please. Besides you don't change row of any list items here , you just change the data source.

Comment: What other code should I be showing, the records are being populated from CloudKit other than that I have shown how the list is shown and how i am handling `onDelete()`.

Comment: after 'recordsHandler.audioRecords.remove(atOffsets: offsets)', what's your goal?

Comment: to know which record from recordsHandler.audioRecords was deleted so I can access it's properties (one of them being a CKRecord.ID)

Comment: Yes, the `row` is the index was deleted. You may need to save it some where.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202359/discussion-between-nix-codes-and-e-coms).